# Enforce the use of the "this" and "base" at compile-time in Visual Studio/C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, compiler-construction

When extending classes, I find it very descriptive to use the `base` (`MyBase` in VB) keyword when accessing methods in the base-class. And the `this` (`Me` in VB) keyword when accessing functions in the class extending the base-class. That goes for a "flat" structure with no inheritance as well.

I find it easier to read this:

```
public class World
{
    public String baseName = "World";
}


public class Hello : World
{
    public String thisName = "Hello";


    public String GetNames()
    {
        return this.thisName + " " + base.baseName;
    }
}
```

Than this:

```
...

    public String GetNames()
    {
        return thisName + " " + baseName;
    }

...
```

Now, my question is: is it possible to enforce the use of `this` and `base` at compile-time in Visual Studio/C#, so that the compiler throws an error or a warning if you do not use these keywords in your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at StyleCop.

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/sourceanalysis

There are some rules in there that should do what you want.
You can configure it to show any style violations as warnings or errors.

Comment: FYI, by default, StyleCop enforces this (as an alternative to some sort of member-data naming convention) and discourages superfluous base specifications.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work with Visual Studio Team System 2008. The install works fine, but VS crashes when I try to use the plug-in. This is on a clean install of VS, with no addons installed.

Comment: We use StyleCop 4.3 with Visual Studio Team System 2008 in both plain and (just upgraded) SP1 variants and it works fine, so there isn't any fundamental incompatibility (though unfortunately this doesn't help with your problem, just letting you know it can work OK).

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to check out [SSW's code auditor](http://www.ssw.com.au/ssw/CodeAuditor/)

Unfortunately there is no way that I'm aware of to enforce this in the compiler.